# Does icecream sandwich 4.0.3 enforces more restrictions for application developer in threading usage?

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-anr-dialog

I am working on an application that was designed for tablet (specifically tested well on Motorola Xoom and Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1). The O.S. which was used was HoneyComb.

Recently after updating the O.S. to official Icecream Sandwich 4.0.3, that was received as notification update, I find the application is not at all well.
It lags in performance, gives frequent ANR ( Application not responding ) dialogs.

While I understand the ANR are related to performing more work in the UI thread, i need to know does this new android version 4.0.3 enforces more strict restrictions on number of threads that runs in background ? Or killing them as the activity exists that started it ?

Application uses threads exclusively to load images from server in list views. Switching between screens makes each individual image holder to start a new thread for its loading.
Retesting it on Honeycomb makes it work perfectly fine but not with 4.0.3, Why ?

Question is on whether icecream sandwich 4.0.3 makes changes in this area at O.S. level handling of threads or activity lifecycle for developers ?

Answer (score 0):

There are no major changes in the Activity lifecycle in ICS.

Activity lifecycle can be found here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

You should not be performing heavy work on the UI thread.  In the `Settings` activity in ICS under `Developer options` you can enable `Strict mode` and a few other options that will help you see performance issues in your program, such as CPU usage.

Comment: Thanks. Yes activity life cycle is same. But only wanted to know if any changes were made at handling of it at O.S. level. (Just some guess)